# Как очищать с помощью ClearRenderTargetView() в d3d11 только часть окна как это делается в d3d12?

Tags: c++, windows, графика, directx

В d3d12 можно передать *rects которые нужно очищать. В d3d11 этого нет. Я использовал RSSetScissorRects() но это только ограничивает область рисования. Как мне очищать только область Viewport а не весь экран? Слышал про SV_ViewportArrayIndex. Но пока не знаю как это использовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `ID3D11DeviceContext1::ClearView`. Параметры там аналогичны `ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::ClearRenderTargetView`, только указатель на прямоугольники и их количество идут в обратном порядке.

Comment: Спасибо это понятно. А с ClearDepthStencilView() проблем не будет?

Comment: @DownloaderGames Какие проблемы имеются ввиду?

Comment: я имел ввиду смогу ли очищать буфер глубины по rect. Но я уже разобрался спасибо